# Should event-related topics be allowed?

Tags: discussion

Should be allowed questions like "Where AnimExpo will be?" or "How many people went to Comiket 83?" be allowed?
Some could be intereting, while lots others will not as being too localized, so should there be a policy regarding this?

Comment: Why the downvotes? Isn't It a common sense question?

Comment: Downvotes on metas mean disagreement. It usually has nothing to do with the quality of the question.

Comment: Downvotes usually come from people indicating that "I don't agree with the premise/argument provided by the question". In this scenario, I assume that people are assuming your stance as "yes" and are downvoting as an indication of "no".

Comment: I understand. I'm not yet fully familiar with the way of things around here.
[Offtopic]FYI, in some spanish communities with voting like this where I am, usually the downvote means things like "totally unrelated", "off-topic" or "don't make any sense, delete it", that's why I said that.[/Offtopic]

Comment: It's a confusing system made all the more confusing when equally controversial questions can sometimes just get upvoted because "Hey, this is a useful thing to ask about". I'm glad that this is a learning experience, though, however confounding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd hate to [parrot myself](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27/what-do-we-do-with-questions-about-future-events-releases/43#43) about being a news outlet so fresh into a site, hahaha. But I would basically think that at this point, the question feels less about the subject matter and more about, well, us, the people and consumers of it. I'd consider it not really applicable for the main site Q&A before we even reach that point.

That said, organizing community meetups at these kind of events is not something foreign for using the meta site, or the chat service. Although, with the sheer number of conventions that are around for these kind of things, it might be a bit better to have a dedicated chat channel for local meetups, and reserve giant meetup threads for them real big ones.

Answer (score 4):

I'd argue against.

It's out of the scope of Anime/Manga, even if it's related.