# 2014 Edition: How should we treat questions regarding future unannounced events?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

[Quite awhile ago](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27/what-do-we-do-with-questions-about-future-events-releases), I asked the question https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3372/will-there-be-a-continuation-of-sword-art-online and recently the answer to this question came available and was wondering:

- *How should we treat questions that ask about future unannounced events?*
- *And if allowed, how broad (in terms of timeframe) should we allow these questions to be ?*

Another example would be: https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5398/new-dragon-ball-z-series

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do we do with questions about future events/releases?](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/27/what-do-we-do-with-questions-about-future-events-releases)

Comment: @ToshinouKyouko With a new year comes a new perspective. Lets see if the community's opinions have changed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think questions about future series should be categorized as off-topic.

One cannot absolutely base an answer off of time since the series ended. For example, it is possible a series with a large fanbase could have an addition series release 7/8 years later.

One could estimate an answer basing off the content left to cover if the show is based off a manga/light novel, such as Sword Art Online and perhaps with a combination of ratings and popularity thrown in. However, no-one apart from the people involved in the process is going to know much.

Often details of future events can be rumours or there can be cancellations, so answers can be based off of volatile information.

The problem is that there are some questions that ARE answerable, that we will miss out on if we close all these questions. But I think the benefits of these few questions being answered are highly outweighted by lots of unanswerable or volatile questions.

I suggest, much like @GraceNote's post on [What do we do with questions about future events/releases?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27/what-do-we-do-with-questions-about-future-events-releases) back in '12, that we leave future events to new sources such as ANN or Crunchyroll.

Answer (score 5):

When a question about the occurence of a future event is asked. Only one of two outcomes is possible:

- Either the event does not happen, then the question will never have a definite answer, and as such, is not answerable.
- Or the event does happen, then the question loses its usefulness (because it's like asking "Will the world end in 2012?", not very effective, is it?)

As such, question regarding future unannounced events should (still) be treated as off-topic.